# Implementing a safe wrapper for resource consumption in Rust

Tags: rust, unsafe

Abstract: I am working with a resource consumer type `Consumer` and a resource type `Resource`. The relevant portion of the API is as follows:

```rust
impl Consumer {
   pub fn consume(&self, r: Resource);
}
```

The API is such that there is no other safe way of having the `Consumer` consume the resource. `Resource` is not `Copy`.

I would like to create a type `WithConsumer<‘a>` with the following interface:

```rust
impl<‘a> WithConsumer<‘a> {
    pub fn new(r: Resource, c: &’a Consumer) -> Self;
    pub fn into_inner(self) -> Resource;
}

impl<‘a> AsRef<‘a, Resouce> for WithConsumer<‘a>;

impl<‘a> AsMut<‘a, Resource> for WithConsumer<‘a>;

impl<‘a> Drop for WithConsumer<‘a>;
```

where the code `std::men::drop(WithConsumer::new(resource, consumer))` should be equivalent to `consumer.consume(resource)`, and all the other implementation details should have their obvious properties.

Obviously, this cannot be done in Safe Rust. Here is an unsafe implementation (obvious bits omitted):

```
use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;

pub struct WithConsumer<‘a> {
   r: ManuallyDrop<Resource>,
   c: &’a Consumer,
}

impl WithConsumer<‘a> {
    pub fn into_inner(mut self) -> Resource {
        unsafe {
            let answer = ManuallyDrop::take(&mut self.r);
            std::mem::forget(self);
            answer
        }
    }
}

impl<‘a> Drop for WithConsumer<‘a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {       self.c.consume(ManuallyDrop::take(&mut self.r))
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a safe abstraction? Is there any part of the standard library or any good crate on crates.io that has already done something like this? It seems like an obvious enough issue that it should have a well-known and already written solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should use `Option` instead of unsafe code. This introduces `unwrap()`s, but none of them will ever panic unless there is a bug in the implementation, since the `Option` is only `None` when the `WithConsumer` is about to be dropped.

```rust
pub struct Resource;

pub struct Consumer;

impl Consumer {
    pub fn consume(&self, _r: Resource) {}
}

pub struct WithConsumer<'a> {
    r: Option<Resource>,
    c: &'a Consumer,
}

impl<'a> WithConsumer<'a> {
    pub fn new(r: Resource, c: &'a Consumer) -> Self {
        Self { r: Some(r), c }
    }
    pub fn into_inner(mut self) -> Resource {
        self.r.take().unwrap()
    }
}

impl AsRef<Resource> for WithConsumer<'_> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Resource {
        self.r.as_ref().unwrap()
    }
}

impl AsMut<Resource> for WithConsumer<'_> {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Resource {
        self.r.as_mut().unwrap()
    }
}

impl Drop for WithConsumer<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if let Some(r) = self.r.take() {
            self.c.consume(r);
        }
    }
}
```

This does use an additional byte in `WithConsumer` to store the `Option` state (unless the `Resource` type has a *niche* that can be used). However, unless you have a very strong requirement for memory-usage efficiency, it is not a wise tradeoff to reach for unsafe code to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks! For practical purposes, this should be zero-overhead, since the compiler should be able to optimise away the unwrapping for most use cases. Therefore, it seems there is little point in going the extra mile with unsafe code here. I was originally pondering this when I was thinking about a version where the resource itself was an Option and wondering how to extend it to resources that weren’t options, but I didn’t think to just wrap in an option.

Comment: @MarkSaving There _is_ overhead in storing the `Option` discriminant in `WithConsumer`. I edited my answer to discuss that.

Comment: True, but I strongly suspect that in my use case, the compiler will be able to optimise the `WithConsumer` away entirely in most cases (not to mention that in my case, the null pointer optimisation applies). We could actually guarantee the null pointer optimisation applies by slightly changing the definition to be a wrapper around Option<(Resource, &Consumer)>.